# How to execute every single test in a test class in an own process

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, nunit, tdd

We use **C#** and **NUnit 3.6.1** in our project and we think of parallel test execution to reduce the duration. As far as I know, it is possible to parallel the execution of `TestFixture` with a `Parallelizable`-attribute for the class in an assembly. We want to go further and parallel all tests, that are marked with `Test`or `TestCase`, inside a test class.

**A typical test class looks like:**

```
[TestFixture]
    public class MyTestClass
    {

      private MySUT _sut;
      private Mock<IDataBase> _mockedDB;

      [SetUp]
      public void SetUpSUT()
      {
        _mockedDB = new Mock<IDataBase>();
        _sut = new MySUT(_mockedDB.Object);
      }

      public void TearDownSUT()
      {
        _mockedDB = null;
        _sut = null;
      }

      [Test]
      public void MyFirstTC()
      {
        //Here do some testing stuff with _sut
      }

      [Test]
      public void MySecondTC()
      {
        //Here do some testing stuff with _sut again
      }
    }
```

As you can see, we have some fields, that we use in every test. To have a better separation, we think of executing every single test in an own process. I have no idea how to do that, or do we have to change something different to make parallel execution possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess this would be down to the test runner.  I believe NCrunch will do this, but not sure about the standard Test Adapter.  NCrunch isn't free though (though I would recommend it)

Comment: NCrunch is a great product. Some of what it does is now covered by "Live Unit Tests" directly by Visual Studio these days

Comment: As Charlie P. mentions below - NUnit 3.7 allows execution of individual tests in their own threads, not processes: will it help for your case? what is the reason of requiring separate processes? Is there conflict between different tests accessing the same address space?

Comment: We see a problem in the SetUpSUT()/TearDownSUT() methods. If every test runs in his own thread, there might be some concurrency for _sut. 
For example one test creates the _sut and another set _sut to null.

Comment: Right - so there are dependencies between the tests... can't it be fixed first (e.g. - each test using their own copy of the SUT, as it seems like a mock object it shouldn't be an issue)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can run individual tests in separate threads (not processes), starting with NUnit 3.7.
Using the `ParellelScope` parameter to `Parallelizable` attribute. From [NUnit documentation](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Parallelizable-Attribute):

**ParallelScope Enumeration**
This is a `[Flags]` enumeration used to specify which tests may run in parallel. It applies to the test upon which it appears and any subordinate tests. It is defined as follows:

```
[Flags]
public enum ParallelScope
{
    None,     // the test may not be run in parallel with other tests
    Self,     // the test itself may be run in parallel with other tests
    Children, // child tests may be run in parallel with one another
    Fixtures  // fixtures may be run in parallel with one another
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is incorrect in terms of the question, which asks if there is a way to run the tests in a separate process. The `ParallelScope` enumeration applies to running tests on parallel threads within the same process.

Comment: Thanks - missed that! I've updated my answer accordingly, as it seems like separate threads may be helpful as well.

Answer (score 2):

NUnit has no builtin way to run individual tests in separate processes. It allows you to run entire assemblies in separate processes or individual tests within an assembly on separate threads, as you have discovered already.

The question has come up in the past as a possible extension to NUnit, but has never been acted on up to now because there doesn't seem to be a very wide demand for it.

Not a real positive answer, I'm afraid. :-(

Answer (score 0):

In VSTS, you can check a box to isolate tests. You can also run in parallel or in series. In Visual Studio, I dont think its obvious/possible to do this. If its possible in VSTS, there is probably a command line you can use to pass the appropriate switches.